# Add watermark to PDF using Zend Framework (adding something under the text layer)

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

I'm trying to dynamically watermark a pdf file using PHP with Zend_Pdf.

Is there a way to de-layer a PDF file, put something (text, image) between the background and text layer, and then save it?

Is there like a z-index for PDF files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a type of Z-index but there's nothing that can actually manipulate it pragmatically. I've been trying to do similar for over a month.
I've tried: Zend, FPDF, AcroJS, PyPDF, ImageMagick and GhostScript with no luck.

The only way I've been able to add something "under" something else in a PDF is to rebuild it from the bottom up.

Example: I needed to add a photograph under an employee barcode.
First I cropped the PDF to the just the barcode (my_crop.py - Python)
Then I converted it to tiff copy (imagemagick)
Next I added the employee photo to the original PDF (Zend framework)
Finally I added the barcode tiff from the first step (Zend framework)

It's not in any way perfect but it's the only thing I could get anywhere near what I wanted.